# Newtonsoft.JsonConvert - how to deserialize JavaScript object into an object with one property being Enum?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, json.net

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to use the following code:

```
filters.Filters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchFilterItem>>(customFilterString);
```

The SearchFilterItem is the following class:

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string ColumnName { get; set; }
public string ColumnDisplayName { get; set; }
public SearchColumnTypes ColumnType { get; set; }  //Character, Numeric, Boolean, Date, DateTime. 
public SearchOperators Operator { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
public string Logic { get; set; } //And / Or
```

From JavaScript I'm trying to send the following:

```js
if ($.isNumeric($scope.type)) {
    filter = {
        columnDisplayName: 'Type Id',
        columnName: 'LTypeId',
        columnType: parseInt('1'),
        value: $scope.type.toString(),
        displayValue: $scope.type.toString(),
        strOperator: 'Equals', Logic: "AND"
    };
```

So, my problem here is how to properly send the columnType which is C# Enum?

I'm getting this error in run-time:

> "Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to Siriusware.Models.Messages.SearchColumnTypes."}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException

What should I do?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post a json sample

Answer (score 4):

There is a StringEnumConverter attribute in Newtonsoft.Json which has this exact purpose.
You can check the associated documentation here :

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_converters_stringenumconverter.htm

Here is a blog article giving interesting inputs on the subject, like custom converter for instance :

https://bytefish.de/blog/enums_json_net/

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was my own stupid mistake. In the filterItem class the column type is another class. In that class we have yet one more ColumnType property which is an enum. So, as soon as I changed my JavaScript to use columnType: {ColumnType: 'Numeric'} it did work by itself - no extra changes were needed. I did ask my colleague to help me as well and we spent about an hour or more chasing this down until it finally dawned on me.